# Triggered Send SFMC from Commerce Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, commerce-cloud

I'm creating a connection between Marketing Cloud and Commerce Cloud to, amongst others, send an email based on an action occurred in Commerce Cloud.

Is the process of setting up a triggered send definition in Commerce Cloud similar to that of Sales Cloud? So the setup (such as define trigger definition) is mostly done in Commerce Cloud?